# log4j2: pattern does not contain a date

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j2

I'm trying to migrate to log4j2 and I'm getting an java.lang.IllegalStateException: "Pattern does not contain a date."

I have a filePattern setup for each RollingFile so I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.  FYI, I'm running through Tomcat on Eclipse (Kepler).

Here is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Configuration status="WARN">

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] - %m%n" />
        </Console>

        <RollingFile name="RootFile" fileName="injunction.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false"
            filePattern="injunction.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <!--  Roll over the file to the next day -->
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <!--  Only keep up to 30 archived log files -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingFile>

        <RollingFile name="DBFile" fileName="db.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false"
            filePattern="db.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}">>
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%-5p] - %m%n"/>
            <Policies>
                <!--  Roll over the file to the next day -->
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <!--  Only keep up to 30 archived log files -->
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="30"/>
        </RollingFile>

    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="RootFile" />
        </Root>

        <Logger name="DBLogger" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="DBFile" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy needs date to determine how often the file should roll over

Comment: This is what I found from Apache regarding TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy:

"How often a rollover should occur based on the most specific time unit in the date pattern. For example, with a date pattern with hours as the most specific item and and increment of 4 rollovers would occur every 4 hours. The default value is 1."

Shouldn't the default be 1 day?

Comment: It is based on the smallest unit reflected in your date pattern, which in your case is seconds. You need to set the interval to the number of seconds in a full day if that is what you want.

Also, I think you need to add DatePattern field (it looks like you tried to do it via FilePattern)

Comment: I'll have to put this problem on hold as Eclipse has decided it can no longer find my log4j2.xml file.

Comment: @coffeeaddict can you please elaborate perhaps with an example?

Answer (score 0):

This problem appeared to fix itself.  I moved the log4j2.xml to the top of Eclipse's src directory and that did the trick.